# My JSF application is not working in IE8 but it works in IE7

Tags: java, ajax, internet-explorer, jsf, portlet

My application is a JSF based application. After logging in, I am unable to find correct page layout in my home page. Ajax Event and JSF page navigation is not working. Even pagination is not working. It works in IE6 and IE7 but in IE8 it is not working. Can any one please help me out.

Comment: turns out this should do with CSS standards. Can you please post some code.

Comment: Are you using JSF 1.2 or 2.0? We had the same issue on our site, but I found moving to JSF 2 solved the problem. It turns out the way JSF 1.2 AJAX events are not defined with valid syntax in IE8 or IE9. Sometimes compatibility mode in those browsers helps.

Comment: IE6 does not work like IE7 which doesn't work like IE8 which doesn't work like IE9 which won't work like IE10 and none of them work like any other far more modern browser.

Comment: Please do not post identical duplicates. Please add more detail and better information to your existing question instead

Comment: Please provide feedback to the comments posted as far by improving/editing your question accordingly. Do not copypaste the same question over and over. This ain't going to help us and thus also not yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be compatability Issue. If the problem is the compatability then create a filter and then setthe Request header with following code then You can run IE8 browser with IE7 mode.

```
 "X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE7"
```